# Git, when checkouting file don't upload

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to do a script to remove every .env files on every branch of my project.
Here is the code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function remove_env() {
    if [[ -z $1 ]];then
        echo "Require at least one argument, check help"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [[ $1 == "-h" ]];then
        echo "./env-remover.sh \"<path to the env file>\" -f (optional force everything)"
        exit 1
    fi
    filepath=$1
    remote=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    if [[ -z $2 ]];then
        git filter-repo --path $filepath --invert-paths
        git remote add origin $remote
        git push --set-upstream origin $branch --force
    elif [[ $2 == "-f" ]];then
        git filter-repo --path $filepath --invert-paths --force
        git remote add origin $remote
        git push --set-upstream origin $branch --force
    else
        echo "Bad syntax"
        exit 1
    fi
}

force=""

if [ -n $1 ] && [ "$1" == "-f" ]; then
    force="-f"
    echo "Force enabled"
fi


for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)'); do
    true_branch_name=$(echo $branch | sed -e 's/\origin\///g')
    git checkout -f $true_branch_name > /dev/null
    env_file=$(find . -type f -name ".env" ! -path "./front-web/*" ! -path "./area_api/node_modules/*" | cut -c 3-) # there is only 1 .env so I don't need to parse multiple responses
    if [ -z $env_file ]; then
        echo -e "\e[32mno .env in $true_branch_name\e[0m"
    else
        echo -e "\e[31m\e[1m\e[4m.env founded at $env_file in $true_branch_name\e[0m"
        remove_env $env_file $force
    fi
done
```

The thing is that he find a .env on a branch and he delete it, but after that he checkout on other branches but he doesn't find .env but there are .env on the other branches

Do you have any idea of why it doesn't update files

Comment: side comment : the `remote=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)` followed by `git remote add origin $remote` seems useless : either `origin` is configured (you will get a URL, but you don't need to set it), or `origin` isn't configured (in that case, `$remote` will be empty, and `git add origin ""` isn't helpful). Did you have a reason to do this action ?

Comment: if your intention is to iterate on remote branches from `origin` : `git for-each-ref ... refs/remotes/origin`. Also, to debug your iteration, print the name of the ref you are processing (before running `git checkout` : `echo $branch $true_branch_name`

Comment: Why do you need to run a loop? `git filter-repo` can rewrite multiple refs at once.